# Virtualbox: How to set up network so guest machines can all talk to each other and still be accessed by host machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

I was wondering if someone could give me a simple guide on how to set up virtual networking in VirtualBox (6.1.6) so that the following prerequisites can be met:

- Guests can talk to each other (Ping, etc.)
- Host can talk to Guest Machines (Ping, etc.)
- Host can access Guest Machine via SSH on Putty.exe

Because I have been trying to set up a simple connection between Guest 1 (10.0.0.1) and Guest 2 (10.0.0.2) via a NAT Network (With DHCP) to no avail, resulting in Guest 1 being able to ping Guest 2, but Guest 2 can't ping Guest 1 for some weird reason.

The Host is running Windows 10 64 Bit
Guest 1 is running Windows 10 64 Bit
Guest 2 is running CENTOS 7

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me figure this out, as I can't get it no matter how I tinker.

Comment: Make sure you have VBOX Guest Extensions installed on every Guest.  I have two Linux Guests here on the same subnet with VMware Workstation and NAT networking. They can ping and see each other. Try that.

Comment: Use bridged networking.  This is easiest way to do it, you'll need IP addresses available for all 3.